# 2-digit combinations

Tags: combinatorics

I can count the number 2-digit combinations: each digit has 10 possibilities, so that gives 10*10 = 100 combinations.

But what if we write the combinations in one long string like this:

112131

This string is 6 long, but it gives us 5 combinations: 11, 12, 13, 21 and 31

How can I calculate the shortes string that gives me all 100 combinations? How long will it need to be for all n-digit combinations? How can i generate the sequence?

I remember hearing about this somewhere but i forgot. If I could just get a name of what it is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably thinking of [De Bruijn sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence).  These are often [generated for a binary "alphabet"](http://duch.mimuw.edu.pl/~rytter/TEACHING/TEKSTY/PreferOpposite.pdf), but can be formed for any size $k$ alphabet.

With wraparound the minimum sequence length of $k^n$ for all $n$ subsequences on an alphabet of size $k$ can be obtained.

If wraparound is not allowed, then the sequence has to be "padded" with the first $n-1$ characters repeated at the end, for a total length of $k^n + n - 1$.

The [Combinatorial Object Server](http://theory.cs.uvic.ca/cos.html) has a De Bruijn sequence generator (among other things), and for $n=2, k=10$ as in the Question, it produced this (lexicographically least) sequence:

```
0010203040506070809112131415161718192232425262728293343536373839445464748495565758596676869778798899
```

Comment: If you are interested in learning how this sort of thing might be coded then have a look at the program for three-letter DeBruijn sequences that I posted [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486753/shortest-ternary-string-containing-all-ternary-strings-of-length-3).

Comment: Here's [an implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10547033/487781) for binary sequences I did in Prolog.